# Implement Bootstrap Nav Bar on Own Site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

Was wondering if there was a simple way of implementing the navbar from [this site](http://w3goods.com/gallery/starnight-free-html5css3-website-template) onto my website. I have tried copying the source code from the html file to my page, and linking the bootstrap.min.css file to my site's html page, but I cannot get the navbar to work. The button's image doesn't come, and, when clicked in the place the button would usually be, the navbar doesn't show.

Is there a simple way of putting this into my site, without copying useful and non-useful source code onto my page and hoping it would work?

Could someone please highlight the code that I would need to copy to my site, for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough just to link the `bootstrap.min.css` file to make Bootstrap work. You'll also need some scripts: `bootstrap.min.js` is a must and you're probably going to need [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) as well.

Also, be sure to link to the `bootstrap.min.css` file from that template, which could be a modified version of Bootstrap's original template.